# After uploading .aab file it is not showing app size based on mobile architecture

Tags: android, ffmpeg, 32bit-64bit, android-ffmpeg

In my project i am using assets ffmpeg static binarie files for both 32 and 64 bit it's working fine in both mobile architectures but i have problem about .aab file size. The app size is increased to 17mb after adding 64 bit file,I am using .aab file for uploading but the size is same for both the architectures.Please tell me how to reduce app size based on mobile architecture thank you.

Comment: You can upload multiple apk with different abiFilters (64 bit OR 32 bit)

Comment: yes but i want this in .aab file uploading concept,because aab is the option introduced for dynamic delivery concept,but i don't know how to create aab for that.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should switch from assets to lib container for that. You will find that this is also necessary to run on Android Q. See https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/pull/130 to get a gist of it.

Comment: in this ffmpeg library also using the assets binary files only..see this link.. https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/tree/master/android-ffmpeg/src/main/assets/x86

Comment: That's exactly why I created this pull request